# What is the proper way to judge the quality of education of a university?

Tags: research-process, graduate-school, teaching, ranking

> [Why do Russian and Israeli universities score low in various world rankings?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/46239/why-do-russian-and-israeli-universities-score-low-in-various-world-rankings)

In this question, most of the answers more or less stated that, rankings of universities available on the net are kind of useless.

Then my question is, how can a student judge the quality of education of a university before getting as admission? What factors he/she can observe to take the decision? What information they should collect?

Comment: Is this for graduate or undergraduate study?

Comment: graduate program. some teachers may be expert in research. But, doesn't give enough time in class rooms. May be he stays away for seminars. Then students are screwed up.

Answer (score 3):

The best metric is comparing the quality of current and recent graduate students, in various research outlets. If students from institute X stumble more over questions at conferences compared to those from institute Y, or if they publish in lesser venues, or produce less-solid papers (more errors, more failures to think a problem through), then you can conclude either that Y attracts better students or that Y does a better job of training students than X (I don't think it would matter, for your purposes, which it is). But this is a very labor-intensive evaluation. A second runner-up method would be to look at the job-placement histories of institutions, though getting hired often reflects politics (who your adviser knows, who hates your adviser) as much as student quality.